# PLS-00103 ERROR, what is wrong in the code

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc2_del_rows
        (v_tname        VARCHAR2,
         v_condition    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
AS
        sql_stmt        VARCHAR2(500);
        where_clause    VARCHAR2(200) := 'WHERE'||' '||v_condition;
BEGIN
        IF v_condition IS NULL THEN
            where_clause := NULL;
        END IF;

        sql_stmt := 'DELETE FROM :1'||' '||where_clause;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING v_tname;
        COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your procedure compiles correctly.

Comment: as @mmmmmpie says, the procedure compiles without any error . Are you asking the logic in it or you get that error when you compile ?

Comment: If i pass parameter like proc2_del_rows('EMP', 'DEPTNO = 10') perform successfully. But when i pass parameter like proc2_del_rows('EMP', 'JOB='CLERK') it give error. Then how to pass column that contain string data.

Comment: Do not use comments to add additional information to a question; instead, use the `edit` button (located under the question, below the tags) to edit the question itself. I've done it for you this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The table name can't be a bind variable. Do a `DBMS_ASSERT` on the input table name parameter and make sure it is a valid table name literal, and then directly concatenate it to the delete statement. This will at least protect you against sql injection.

I'd like to know the reason behind doing a delete using a procedure and granting execute on this procedure to individual users, rather than granting a delete on the table to a user directly, which would somewhat be easier to control/restrict. I don't see how this is better in terms on security if that is what you are going for.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE proc2_del_rows
        (v_tname        VARCHAR2,
         v_condition    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
AS
        sql_stmt        VARCHAR2(500);
        where_clause    VARCHAR2(200) := 'WHERE'||' '||v_condition;
BEGIN
        IF v_condition IS NULL THEN
            where_clause := NULL;
        END IF;

        sql_stmt := 'DELETE FROM '||v_tname||' '||where_clause;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

END;
/
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

To include a single-quote character within a string literal you need to double up the single quotes, as in `proc2_del_rows('EMP', 'JOB=''CLERK''')`.

[Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#i38404)